# DIY G-code from scratch. (in BASIC)

Tags: parsing, basic, g-code

Does anyone know where I can find the parameters and mathematical formulas for the G-code commands if I want to program a G-code interpreter from scratch.

Been using Google but can't find anything that explains it or gives a simple list over them.

I have a idea for a project where I want to control a CNC machine with an old BASIC computer (Commodore 64 for example) and libraries wont help me to much. why? I like old computers and it's fun to try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A base line reference for the language is easily found at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code.

This doesn't describe how to *implement* these commands,  but it sounds like you want to just generate them (surely you don't intend for the Commodore to *read* and *execute* G commands?  It hasn't got the computational power to do it).

Comment: Hmm, well maybe I could use the C64 as more of a "code" editor that can send the commands to a MC that does the reading and executing of the command.
Hmm suspected it was a bit to much for the C64 but one could dream about it. :D
thinking about using a computer called ABC 80 a Z80 based computer but it will probably be to much for that one as well.